# trying to authenticate users in iOS by sending username/pw to a PHP script

Tags: php, ios

I am trying to authenticate a user by sending a POST request from my iOS app to a php script. Then having the iOS app read the NSHTTPURLResponse to determine whether or not it was successful. My iOS code is shown below, for some reason it says that my NSURLConnection is unused. The int code always shoots back a value of 200.

```
- (void)authenticateUser:(NSString *)aUsername
                password:(NSString *)aPassword
{
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&pw=%@", aUsername, aPassword];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [post length]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://XXX.com/query-db.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    int code = [httpResponse statusCode];

    // Log the response
    NSLog(@"%d", code);
    if(code == 1){
        NSLog(@"received a 1");
        [self updateWorkTime];
        //[self close];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unsuccessul Attempt" message:@"The username or password is invalid, please try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

Additionally, if you want to take a look at my php script, which I entered in dummy variables for and tested to see if it queried the database properly and that checked out... But just in case you're curious.

```
<?php
    $sentUsername = $_POST['username'];
    $sentPW = $_POST['pw'];

    mysql_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx") or die(mysql_error());   
    mysql_select_db("xxx") or die(mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table") or die(mysql_error());  

    $authenticate = 0;

    while($authenticate == 0) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $selectedUsername = $row['username'];
        $selectedPW = $row['pw'];
        $pwComp = strcmp($sentPW, $selectedPW);
        $userComp = strcmp($selectedUsername, $sentUsername);

        if(!$row) break;
        if($selectedPW == $sentPW && $selectedUsername == $sentUsername) {
            $authenticate = 1;
        }
    }
    echo $authenticate;
?>
```

I tried to set the PHP header, but I was unsure how to do that. I appreciate any and all help this community has given me, truly invaluable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '200' code you're getting back is the HTTP status code, indicating that the request was successful.

If you're after the '1' or '0' value being sent back from your PHP script, you should look for it in the `didReceiveData:` delegate method, not `didReceiveResponse:`.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    NSLog(@"authenticate value => %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am after the '1' or '0'... How would you recommend getting it? Right now the response is the entire html/php file that im communicating with.

Comment: Also, my didReceiveData method doesn't seem to be finishing... Any idea why that'd be the case?

Comment: What else is in the response?  In your PHP code in your question is looks like you are only writing out one character: `echo $authenticate;`

Comment: now it doesn't seem to be finishing... I have another NSLog statement right in the didReceiveData method and it isn't making it that far.

Comment: hmm now it's working... The iOS app outputs this:
authenticate value => <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>connecting to the db</title>
</head>
1<body>
</body>
</html>

Comment: So now you just need to parse the HTML response to find the "1".  Look into the NSScanner class for doing that.  Or else you might be able to modify your PHP script so that it returns plain text instead of an HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

You're using NSASCIIStringEncoding - Try using NSUTF8StringEncoding - you might be losing it in the conversion to the NSData object.

Also, you should be using HTTPS otherwise your passwords are visible to all :-)